# Using jQuery or JavaScript to find multiples and remainder of 2 numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery

Odd task, but I need to take a given integer, and first divide it by 5, whatever is left, divide by 3, and then show whatever remains.

For instance:

```
var fives = 19 / 5 = 3 remainder 4
var threes = 4 / 3 = 1 remainder 1
var ones = 1


var fives // 3
var threes // 1
var ones // 1
```

I can divide and see if it's a multiple, but I'm not sure how to do the conditional statement to pass it through the 2 operations and leave the remainders each time. The integers will always be positive numbers, no decimals.

Comment: If you want to "take a given integer, and first divide it by 5, whatever is left, divide by 3, and then show whatever remains", then would it be sufficient to just use the modulo operator? ie, `19 % 5 % 3 // evaluates to 1`?

Answer (score 1):

To get the remainder of a division you have to devide, floor it and multiply it again. That result you have to substrate from your starting number.

Example:

```
Remainder of 19 / 5: 19 - floor(19 / 5)*5 = 19 - 15 = 4
```

in javascript code it's:

```
var remainderOf = (a,b)=>a-Math.floor(a / b)*b;
// calling it:
var result = remainderOf(19, 5); // 4
```

But the operation sequence: divide, floor, multiply substrate... is known as modulo operation. And you can use it in javascript with the `%`.sign:

```
var remainderOf = (a,b)=>a%b;
```

In your case it should be:

```
var startingNo = 19;
var remainderOfDevisionBy5 = startingNo % 5;
var remainderOfDevisionBy3 = remainderOfDevisionBy5 % 3;
alert(remainderOfDevisionBy3);
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining everything. I am relieved that this wasn't a super obvious answer.

Comment: @mrpatg if it helped you and you like the answer please mark it as the answer so I and the other user can see that this question has already an answer. If you have any further questions on this please feel free to ask :)

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
var number = 19;

var fives = Math.floor(number / 5);
var threes = Math.floor(number % 5 / 3);
var ones = number % 5 % 3;
```